# Microsoft 365 locale formats (date etc.) not consistent with Country

Tags: microsoft365

We have recently set up a new org in Microsoft 365. The issue we're having is all of our users/apps are defaulting to "US" formats - mm/dd/yy, Letter page sizes, etc. Our "Country" is set to "Australia" on the main Org Information panel in the admin center.

Does anyone know how to force all of the formats to adhere to the org country?

*Note: Some defaults can be fixed manually in a specific app, but some cant be (e.g. Planner date format stays mm/dd/yy)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it's not possible. All of the defaults are set to US and users need to manually change each app/platform to their country's defaults.